Fail to deploy alfresco War file Alfresco Comunity edition edition v23.2.1
I am new to Alfresco and need assistance with installing it on an Ubuntu Server 24.04. After installing Ubuntu Server, PostgreSQL, JDK 21, and Tomcat, the deployment of the Alfresco.war file fails. You can see the error in the screenshot from the app manager. I am working on a freshly installed Ubuntu Server 24.04 with an Intel i7 processor and 16GB RAM. I would appreciate your help. Thank you .
app manager
error
catalina.log file
i try to deploy the alfresco.war file but it does not work
that's the start content of alfresco.log
    2024-05-29 11:03:46,743 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer#0' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customPropertyEditorRegistrar' while setting bean property 'propertyEditorRegistrars' with key [0]
2024-05-29 11:03:46,751 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer#0' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customPropertyEditorRegistrar' while setting bean property 'propertyEditorRegistrars' with key [0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:460) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:191) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:191) ~[spring-context-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:779) ~[spring-context-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597) ~[spring-context-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:394) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:274) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70) ~[classes/:23.2.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3997) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4424) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:599) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:571) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:654) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:969) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1703) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:264) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.24]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:803) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:250) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:177) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[servlet-api.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:428) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:597) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:663) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[catalina.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-util.jar:10.1.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) [?:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customPropertyEditorRegistrar' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'NamespaceService' while setting bean property 'namespaceService'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dictionaryDAO' defined in class path resource [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantService' while setting bean property 'tenantService'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tenantService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-23.2.0.60.jar!/alfresco/mt/mt-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'tenantAdminDAO' while setting bean property 'tenantAdminDAO'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]

that's the content of catalina.log file
    29-May-2024 09:25:58.014 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.1.24
29-May-2024 09:25:58.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 9 2024 17:41:23 UTC
29-May-2024 09:25:58.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.1.24.0
29-May-2024 09:25:58.038 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
29-May-2024 09:25:58.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.8.0-31-generic
29-May-2024 09:25:58.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
29-May-2024 09:25:58.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-21-oracle-x64
29-May-2024 09:25:58.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           21.0.3+7-LTS-152
29-May-2024 09:25:58.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
29-May-2024 09:25:58.039 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/alfresco/tomcat
29-May-2024 09:25:58.040 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/alfresco/tomcat
29-May-2024 09:25:58.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/alfresco/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
29-May-2024 09:25:58.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
29-May-2024 09:25:58.161 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
29-May-2024 09:25:58.161 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
29-May-2024 09:25:58.161 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
29-May-2024 09:25:58.161 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
29-May-2024 09:25:58.162 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
29-May-2024 09:25:58.162 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
29-May-2024 09:25:58.162 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
29-May-2024 09:25:58.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
29-May-2024 09:25:58.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/alfresco/tomcat
29-May-2024 09:25:58.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/alfresco/tomcat
29-May-2024 09:25:58.164 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/alfresco/tomcat/temp
29-May-2024 09:25:58.168 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
29-May-2024 09:25:58.946 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-May-2024 09:25:58.984 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1609] milliseconds
29-May-2024 09:25:59.086 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
29-May-2024 09:25:59.086 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.24]
29-May-2024 09:25:59.179 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/share.war]
29-May-2024 09:26:12.068 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-May-2024 09:26:23.046 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/share.war] has finished in [23,847] ms
29-May-2024 09:26:23.047 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
29-May-2024 09:26:23.145 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-May-2024 09:26:23.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [99] ms
29-May-2024 09:26:23.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/manager]
29-May-2024 09:26:23.264 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-May-2024 09:26:23.271 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [124] ms
29-May-2024 09:26:23.271 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/examples]
29-May-2024 09:26:23.577 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-May-2024 09:26:23.590 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [318] ms
29-May-2024 09:26:23.590 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/docs]
29-May-2024 09:26:23.679 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-May-2024 09:26:23.681 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [91] ms
29-May-2024 09:26:23.682 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
29-May-2024 09:26:23.792 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
29-May-2024 09:26:23.794 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [113] ms
29-May-2024 09:26:23.798 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
29-May-2024 09:26:23.848 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [24862] milliseconds
29-May-2024 09:26:55.953 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war]
29-May-2024 09:27:08.603 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
29-May-2024 09:27:08.604 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/alfresco] startup failed due to previous errors
29-May-2024 09:27:08.639 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco.war] has finished in [12,686] ms


What does your alfresco.log file say about why it didn't start?

i updated the log file

did you follow the steps described in Install with zip?

It seems you have not installed the Alfresco correctly, does it connect to your DB ? When you receive a context instatiation error it could depends on many different things, libraries (.jar) or wrong xml context files
